# How do you setup the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code to use the proper font family?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run an integrated terminal in VSCode the fonts do not look as expected.  This is especially evident with using a theme with custom font symbols such as [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) and you might end up with something that looks like this

[image].

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since you are using Powerlevel10k, I suggest that you follow the instructions from that project: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can:

- Go to File --> Preferences --> Settings
- Select the correct tab (User, an SSH remote, etc.) - you will often be safe selecting User
- Search for fontFamily
- From the tree on the left select Features --> Terminal (1)
- Enter the Font Family name.  For Windows 10 you can find the correct name by clicking the Windows icon in the taskbar, searching for Font Settings and then - in the box that appears - searching for the font in "Available Fonts".  The correct font name will be below the sample of the font and right above the number of available font faces.
- Save the updated preferences and the terminal font for Visual Studio Code will change immediately